# Parse a value from manifest.yaml file and store it's corresponding block name into an array

Tags: shell, ubuntu, yaml, sh, app.yaml

I have a manifest.yaml file

```html
-test1:
    name: test1
    description: this is test1
    label: label1 label2

-test2:
    name: test2
    description: this is test2
    label: label3 label2
    
-test3:
    name: test3
    description: this is test3
    label: label3 label1
```

In my shell script , I want to achieve two goals

1. create a function, which will take label name as an input and return array of the tests containing that label

For example : if the input parameter is "lable1" , the function should return [test1,test3]
: if the input parameter is "lable2" , the function should return [test1,test2]

2. create a function , which will take testName as an input and return content of entire block

For example : if the input parameter is "test1" , the function should return:

```html
-test1:
    name: test1
    description: this is test1
    label: label1 label2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bash way of doing it. Maybe you could improve it or adapt it more to what you want to do. In this example we perfom the two function in the same, the result depends on the arg. You can modify it by putting your own regex.

```
#!/bin/bash

function search {

    searcha=$1
    if [[ ${searcha}  =~  test ]]; then
        searcht=true #the arg is a test
    else
        searcht=false #the arg is a label
    fi
    
    
    test=""
    name=""
    desc=""
    label=""
    i=0
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
    
    if [[ $i == 0 ]] ; then
        [[ ${line}  =~  ^-.*:$ ]] && test=${line} && i=1 
    elif [[ $i == 1 ]]; then
        [[ ${line}  =~  name: ]] && name=${line} && i=2
    elif [[ $i == 2 ]]; then
        [[ ${line}  =~  description: ]] && desc=${line}  && i=3
    elif [[ $i == 3 ]]; then
        [[ ${line}  =~  label: ]] && label=${line} && i=4
    fi
    
    if [[ $i == 4 ]]; then
        if $searcht; then
        if [[ $test =~ $searcha ]]; then
            echo $test
            echo $name
            echo $desc
            echo $label
            return 0
        fi
        else
        if [[ $label =~ $searcha ]]; then
            echo ${test:1:${#test} -2}
        fi
        fi
        i=0
    fi
    done < manifest.yaml
}

result=$(search $1)

for ix in ${!result[*]}
do
    printf "%s\n" "${result[$ix]}"
done
```